# "In the Preface to his doctoral thesis" or "In the Preface of his doctoral thesis"?

Tags: prepositions

> During his student days in Berlin and for a year or two afterwards
> Marx was close to Bruno Bauer, a lecturer in theology and a leading
> Young Hegelian. Under Bauer’s influence Marx seized on orthodox
> religion as the chief illusion standing in the way of human
> self-understanding. The chief weapon against this illusion was
> philosophy. **In the Preface to his doctoral thesis**, Marx wrote:

> Philosophy makes no secret of it. The proclamation of Prometheus – in
> a word, I detest all the gods – is her own profession, her own slogan
> against all the gods of heaven and earth who do not recognize man’s
> self-consciousness as the highest divinity. There shall be no other
> beside it. (D 12–13)

It is from "Marx. A very short introduction".

And my question is, why use to in "In the Preface to his doctoral thesis"?

In my idea, the preface belongs to the doctoral thesis, so we should use "of" here.

From [Oxford Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/of)

[image]

So, in this case, which preposition is proper, "of" or "to"?

Comment: Your idea is wrong. Prepositions don't follow rational rules. You just have to learn how to use them. **To** is correct.

Comment: @RonaldSole I am almost sure that, "in the preface of X" can be a legitimate idiomatic phrase although I am not a native speaker of English

Comment: I feel like, "of" just would not impart the feeling of something being prefaced to something else in the logical sense. On the other hand with "to", I instantly feel like something is prefaced prior to something else. Like, "to" imparts a "towards" kind of feeling.

Comment: @Cardinal As you say, a Google Ngrams search confirms the occasional use of **of**. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+preface+to%2Cin+the+preface+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20preface%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20preface%20of%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"In the Preface **of** his doctoral thesis" suggests that the preface is an integral part **of** the thesis itself.

Whereas "In the Preface **to** his doctoral thesis" suggests that the preface is a separate item but linked **to** the content of the thesis.

I believe that using **to** would be better in this case as the preface is a separate item to the main content of the thesis itself.

The same would apply to "In the **introduction to** his doctoral thesis" but we would use "In the **main section of** his doctoral thesis"

Comment: Great analysis and welcome to ELL!